# How can you mount a device using just java?

Tags: java, linux, mount

Okay, I realize this might not be possible ...

I have a device that runs linux, and it will likely not have a user interface that is visible. It will have a USB port that is open ... I want to be able to write java to allow the overall system to detect when a device is plugged into the USB port and then mount the device.

I know how to do this from a command line, but it requires "sudo" to fork a new process with elevated privilege to perform the task. I don't know how to write a java program that can get around (yes, I want to get around) the security protection of mount.

runtime.exec() doesn't really do what I am hoping to accomplish. Is this a "can't be done in Java" problem?

I'm hoping to do this without resorting to external executable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get around the security protection of mount. The protection is not in mount. The protection is in the kernel.

If by chance you find a way and publish it, it will get removed.

If you have control of the OS you are running on, you can add the option user to the mountpoint in /etc/fstab. After doing so, "mount /path" and "umount /path" work from `runtime.exec()` without elevation. `mount` and `umount` are setuid-root to allow this to work.

Comment: Figured it was (that is why the "might not be possible). Best I think I can hope for is runtime.exec() at this point. Just seems like something that is *so* useful that there ought to be a way to do this in java without having to call to an external program. I realize the problems with trying to do that, but you can always hope.

Comment: I could wish that linux could add a feature than would allow a java class to be registered in some way (yeah, "insert magic here ...") to allow a single class to be able to elevate. Linux just isn't there yet.

Comment: @BrianWithnell: The registration is called setuid and it only works for executables.

Comment: @BrianWithnell Would that help? If you had this ability, what would you do to leverage it? (Given that Java has no way to invoke `mount` except through JNI and Runtime.exec)

Comment: I was hoping to not have to have a second process that was tightly coupled to the first. Nothing is actually new information here ... I was just hoping I was missing something stupid. (My being stupid is not a horrible thing.)

Comment: @BrianWithnell: Which is why I added the last paragraph. You can configure your system to allow unprivileged users to perform a specific mount by editing `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not allowed to have the user option ... only specific users are allowed to mount. lol

I'm just going to write the C code as an executable at this point, then grant specific users access to that. It will work. I really do appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

File mounts are controlled by the host operating system. So controlling mounts is done through system calls. You seem to be using  a Unix operating system,  so that means the system call interface is C. So you could use JNI to call a small C function that makes the system call needed.

But all such matters are system dependent, and privileged operations. So that approach creates portability and security problems. So you might do better to reconsider why your program **itself** must do this, rather than letting a control component (such as `systemd`) do it for you.

Comment: The requirement is external ... java is the core of what is being done, and what I'm trying to do is find a method of accomplishing the mount. What I'll probably have to do (at least at this point) is runtime.exec() and sudo mount the device, see if it worked and proceed if it did. sigh